# What is the internals of mongodb 2dsphere index?

Tags: mongodb, geolocation, geospatial, 2dsphere

Mongodb site shows the internals of 2d index is `GeoHash`.

I want to know the internals of 2dsphere index.

Is it `GeoHash`, `Cartesian Tiers` or other techs?

I just find the blog of mongodb site, [new-geo-features](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/50984169045/new-geo-features-in-mongodb-24), to introduce 2dsphere index.

But there is no detail.

Comment: Did you look at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/geospatial-indexes/ ?

Answer (score 4):

The [blog post you linked to](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/new-geo-features-in-mongodb-24) says a few things about how the 2dsphere index is implemented. It uses Google's S2 Geometry Library to create grid cells on the surface of the earth and put them in a B-tree so they can be searched quickly.

The link in the blog post is obsolete, since Google Code is no longer active. The repository for S2 can now be seen [here](https://github.com/google/s2geometry).